# Getting full binary control flow graph from Radare2

Tags: reverse-engineering, control-flow-graph, radare2

I want to get a full control flow graph of a binary (malware) using radare2.
I followed [this post](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9113/how-can-i-generate-a-call-graph-from-an-unstripped-x86-linux-elf) from another question on SO. I wanted to ask if instead of `ag` there is another command that gives the control flow graph of the whole binary and not only the graph of one function.

Comment: Maybe you should ask on https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question should be transfered to the [SE Reverse-engineering website]( https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, make sure to install radare2 from git repository and use the newest version:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/radare/radare2.git
$ cd radare2
$ ./sys/install.sh
```

After you've downloaded and installed radare2, open your binary and perform analysis on it using the `aaa` command:

```
$ r2 /bin/ls
 -- We fix bugs while you sleep.
[0x004049a0]> aaa
[x] Analyze all flags starting with sym. and entry0 (aa)
[x] Analyze function calls (aac)
[x] Analyze len bytes of instructions for references (aar)
[x] Check for objc references
[x] Check for vtables
[x] Type matching analysis for all functions (aaft)
[x] Propagate noreturn information
[x] Use -AA or aaaa to perform additional experimental analysis.
```

Adding `?` after almost every command in radare will output the subcommands. For example, you know that the `ag` command and its subcommands can help you to output the visual graphs so by adding `?` to `ag` you can discover its subcommands:

```
[0x00000000]> ag?
Usage: ag<graphtype><format> [addr]  
Graph commands:
| aga[format]             Data references graph
| agA[format]             Global data references graph
| agc[format]             Function callgraph
| agC[format]             Global callgraph
| agd[format] [fcn addr]  Diff graph
... <truncated> ...

Output formats:
| <blank>                 Ascii art
| *                       r2 commands
| d                       Graphviz dot
| g                       Graph Modelling Language (gml)
| j                       json ('J' for formatted disassembly)
| k                       SDB key-value
| t                       Tiny ascii art
| v                       Interactive ascii art
| w [path]                Write to path or display graph image (see graph.gv.format     and graph.web)
```

You're searching for the `agCd` command which will output a full call-graph of the program in `dot` format.

```
[0x004049a0]> agCd > output.dot
```

The `dot` utility is part of the Graphviz software which can be installed using `sudo apt-get install graphviz`.
You can view your output in any offline [*dot* viewer](http://www.graphviz.org/content/resources), paste the output into an [online Graphviz viewer](http://www.webgraphviz.com/) and even convert the *dot* file to PNG:

```
$ r2 /bin/ls
[0x004049a0]> aa
[x] Analyze all flags starting with sym. and entry0 (aa)
[0x004049a0]> agCd > output.dot
[0x004049a0]> !!dot -Tpng -o callgraph.png output.dot
```

Comment: Thank you for that explanation and the command you found. It answers my question but I wanted to ask if I can get that graph in a python object so that I can run analytics on it.

Comment: Use python r2pipe, it's the easiest way to work with radare from python. Append `j` to almost every command to get Json output. Look at the examples in the repository to learn more: https://github.com/radare/radare2-r2pipe/blob/master/python/README.md

Comment: Cool, but can I get it as a Graph/DiGraph object? With all the nodes and edges connected?

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite understand the question. You can use the Dot output of radare and manipulate it with python however you want, including the graphviz library for python: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz  in addition you can also check this example that may be helpful: https://github.com/radare/radare2-r2pipe/blob/master/python/examples/libgraph.py

Comment: Ah sorry I mean lets say I want this in networkx Graph object so that I can use it's algorithms

Comment: You can convert dot graph to networkx format using from_pydot : https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pydot.from_pydot.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pydot.from_pydot

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for your valuable help!

Comment: Sure! Glad I could help!