# Control flow graph of entire binary file

Tags: reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida, radare2, angr

Is it possible to get the control flow graph of the entire binary file using any disassembler? IDA Pro generates the CFG for each function. Can we use it to get the CFG of the entire program?

Comment: Hello ad99713! In regards to a Radare2 solution take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45426577/getting-full-binary-control-flow-graph-from-radare2?rq=1 .  If the solution does not work for you then go ahead and update your question with the problems you're facing. If you would prefer a non Radare2 solution I suggest removing the Radare2 tag from your question.